# Pandas, series str accessor and SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I have got data frame named "**test_msg**" with columns:
**SMS** - message text,
**Label** - if its spam or not spam (ham)

Whenever I do something like this:

```
test_msg['SMS'] = test_msg['SMS'].str.replace('\W', ' ') #get rid of non-word characters
```

I got SettingWithCopyWarning. Somehow I set values to copy, but Im not sure where is this problem. My original dataframe after this operation is modified.

Could someone help me to crack this problem?

Comment: It works for me. What version are you on? Maybe try test_msg['SMS'] = test_msg['SMS'].str.replace('[\W]', ' ')

Comment: Nope, warning still exist. I got Pandas '1.0.1'.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in this instruction but somewhere **earlier** in your code.

I made such experiment:

1. I created a **source** DataFrame (*df*), containing 3 rows:

   ```
                                SMS  Label
   0           Acdf  xxx  rr  10_20      1
   1     BBbb      x x x  aa  20_30      1
   2  Ccccc##?& ax^ax*ax. aa$ 20_30      1
   ```
2. Then I "copied" some rows from it to *test_msg*:

   ```
   test_msg = df[:2]
   ```

   containing first 2 rows from *df*. But note that I actually did not make
   any copy (no new DataFrame has been created).
   *test_msg* is only a **view** of *df*, i.e. *test_msg* draws data from
   the buffer used by *df*.
3. Now when you atempt to modify this data (referring to *test_msg*),
   *SettingWithCopyWarning* warning occurs.

To cope with this problem, create *test_msg* e.g. using *loc*:

```
test_msg = df.loc[:2]
```

Then *test_msg* is a DataFrame with its **own** data buffer (this time
you just made a copy), so now you can run your the instruction in question
with no warning (try yourself).

Another option is to use *copy()* method:

```
test_msg = df[:2].copy()
```

with the same result.

Comment: You are right! Making .copy() or .loc[] solved it. I didnt know about views and copy in pandas. Thanks to you I got it now.